# Recurrence Relation Closed Formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

Consider the recursion $x_n = 3(x_0x_{n−1} + x_1x_{n−2} + · · · + x_{n−1}x_0)$, with $x_0 = 1$. Find closed form for $x_n$.

Since this is non linear, I cannot assume $x_n=\lambda^{n}$ and try to solve it using a quadratic equation. Is there any tricks I can cancel out terms to find the closed form?

P.S. I did some research and for nonlinear recursion there is no specific rigorous formula I can follow to solve for the closed form so I am wondering if there is a trick in this question.

Comment: A similar equation is mentioned in my combinatorics text (*Applied Combinatorics, Sixth Edition* by Alan Tucker), in the section on solving recurrence relations by generating functions (Chapter 7, Section 5). It is the basically recurrence you have, just without the $3$. The formula precisely is

$$a_n = a_1 a_{n-1} + a_2 a_{n-2} + ... + a_{n-1} a_1$$

The generating function method they use yielded the solution

$$a_n = \frac 1 n \binom{2n-2}{n-1}$$

I'm not sure if it helps much, but looking into stuff based on generating functions would probably help in that respect.

Comment: I took a look at it and its very useful, thanks for your help! So I just multiply 3 to the an closed form you got?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure; I guess so based on MATHS MOD's answer. We won't be covering this exact method until after my spring break though, so I'm simply not sure. For all I know the $3$ renders that method invalid. Sorry that I couldn't help more.